# Selecting element of a list based on the value of the before and next element

Tags: python, list

Suppose I have the following list:

```
l = [2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 3, 1]
```

I want to go through it and pick elements such that the element before and after is bigger than 1, the result should be:

```
[2,2]
```

I tried doing `[i for i in l if i>1]` yet that gives all the elements that are bigger than 1, namely: `[2, 2, 2, 3]`. Note for the 0th element since there is no element before that we should only look up at the 1st element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple approach for you to understand would be using some `for` loops along with conditions based on the criteria you have put forth.

```
out = []

for idx in range(len(l)):
    if idx == 0:  # check to see if it is the first element
        if l[idx + 1] > 1:
            out.append(l[idx + 1])
    else:
        try:
            after = l[idx + 1]  # check to see if we reached the end of the list
        except IndexError:
            break
        
        before = l[idx - 1]
        if before > 1 and after > 1:
            out.append(l[idx])

print(out)
>> [2, 2]
```

Answer (score 0):

The result should be `[2]`, not `[2, 2]`, because for the 0th element the previous element is not defined:

```
lst = [2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 3, 1]
selected_lst = [lst[i] for i in range(1, len(lst) - 1) if lst[i-1] > 1 and lst[i+1] > 1]
print(selected_lst)
# [2]
```

If you really need the edge elements, add them as special cases, for example, add this to the code:

```
if lst[1] > 1:
    selected_lst = [lst[0]] + selected_lst
if lst[-2] > 1:
    selected_lst = selected_lst + [lst[-1]] 
print(selected_lst)
# [2, 2, 1]
```

Note that the selected list will now be `[2, 2, 1]` - still not `[2, 2]` that you mentioned.

Comment: Thank you as mentioned in the question "Note for the 0th element since there is no element before that we should only look up at the 1st element."

Comment: @Wiliam Added handling of the first and last elements.

Comment: thank you, but let me go element by element, the 0th element is 2, there is no 0-1 so we look at 0+1 only that is 2 so we pick the 0th element. Then we look at 1st element the 0th and 2nd element are 2 so we pick the 1st element. The 2nd element is 2, the 1st element is >1 yet the 3rd element is <1 so we do not pick this. Namely the result must only include the zeroth and 1st element or [2,2]

Comment: @Wiliam The last element (1) is also included because the previous element (3) is > 1, and there is no next element. Was my understanding correct?

Answer (score -2):

```
([l[0]] if l[1] > 1 else []) + filter(
  lambda a: a is not None, 
  [b if a > 1 and c > 1 else None for (a,b,c) in zip(l, l[1:], l[2:])])
```

[2, 2]

What's going on here? First you extract 3-tuple (a,b,c) of consecutive numbers and then either return the number in the middle if your condition holds, or None if it doesn't, and then you filter out None-s with a lambda.

I missed "0th element", so adjusted my original code to prepend it in the case when l[1] > 1 using python's wonderful ternary syntax.